# Java Runtime.exec() -- Is it possible to synchronize stream output with wait()/notify()?

Tags: java, multithreading, process, stream, runtime

I have implemented a simple external process executor in Java using Runtime.exec(). I have implemented a "stream gobbler" class that consumes process output from the process's output stream and error stream. My code waits for the external process to complete using Process.waitFor(), then I print the process return code.

The problem I'm experiencing is that the process ends before the "stream gobblers" have finished printing, so in my Java output (System.out), the returned exit code appears in the middle of the process output/error lines.

My question is, Is it possible to synchronize the output on System.out using wait()/notify() instead of polling the alive status of each StreamGobbler in a while loop?

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class RuntimeExecExample
{
    private enum StreamType
    {
        OUTPUT,
        ERROR
    }

    public class MyStreamGobbler extends Thread
    {
        private InputStream is;
        StreamType type;

        public MyStreamGobbler(InputStream is, StreamType type)
        {
            this.is = is;
            this.type = type;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line=null;
                while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(type.toString() + ">" + line);
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void executeCommand(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

            String commandLine = "";
            for(String cmdItem : args)
            {
                commandLine += " " + cmdItem;
            }
            System.out.println("Exec-ing " + commandLine);

            Process proc = rt.exec(args);
            // any error message?
            MyStreamGobbler errorGobbler = new MyStreamGobbler(proc.getErrorStream(), StreamType.ERROR);
            // any output?
            MyStreamGobbler outputGobbler = new MyStreamGobbler(proc.getInputStream(), StreamType.OUTPUT);
            // kick them off
            errorGobbler.start();
            outputGobbler.start();
            // any error???
            int exitVal = proc.waitFor();

            /*
             * Wait for both to finish before printing exit value
             * IS THERE A WAY TO DO THIS WITH wait()/notify() ??
             */
            while(errorGobbler.isAlive())
                ;
            while(outputGobbler.isAlive())
                ;

            System.out.println("ExitValue: " + exitVal);
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        if(args.length < 1)
        {
            System.out.println("USAGE: java RuntimeExecExample <cmd> [<arg1> <arg2> ..]");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            RuntimeExecExample runtimeExecExample = new RuntimeExecExample();
            runtimeExecExample.executeCommand(args);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not something like a count down latch?

Comment: Why are you running your gobblers in a separate thread?

Comment: @EvgeniyDorofeev: the gobblers *should* be run in separate threads.

Comment: So the first workaround I came up with was to collect the output (both streams) in two List<String> instances, then when the external process ends, print both and the exit code to System.out. That solution seemed extreme, and I was wondering if I could just wait on the threads to end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main thread, as well as doing a waitFor() the sub-process to finish, also do errorGobbler.join() and outputGobbler.join(), then you won't need the while(xGobbler.isAlive()).

Answer (score 1):

First, you should call `join()` on any thread that you start.

Second, `System.out` is buffered, so that might explain it. Try calling `System.out.flush()` before reading the contents.

A way to know whether it's a buffering issue would be to temporarily change your invoked process to write into `System.err` instead of `System.out`. `System.err` is not buffered.

Comment: I think System.err is buffered too. See System src: setErr0(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fdErr, 128), true));

Comment: Heads should roll for this. Standard error streams shouldn't be buffered.

Comment: Bizarre, though. I seem to recall SystemErr flushing much quicker than SystemOut.

Comment: System.err.println("111111"); System.out.println("222222"); always prints 222222 111111 in Eclipse (on my PC). But from cmd line its OK

Comment: That might be because Eclipse injects its own `System.out` and `System.err`, so it can display output in the console view.

Comment: Might be so, when I tried this trick new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.err).write("11111".getBytes());  new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out).write("22222".getBytes()); it prints expected 11111 22222

Comment: System.err is buffered. When I test my program using "javac -help", all the output goes to the error stream. The exit code output lands in the middle somewhere.

Comment: Then it must be the `join()` thing, as I wrote above.